# Javascript agglutinative function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, function

Hey guys my question is "What is this , what is the function like this document.getElementById , how can i write a function like this" i am new on it i just want to know how to do it
And i tryed like this

```
function person(something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
    a.something = "value";
```

but i want to rewrite the "getAttribute()" function in my language and in my library. Someone can help me ?
NOTE: Sorry about english i know it is worst ever.

> my wish

```
function say(avalue){
    alert(avalue);
    }
    var a = "something";
    a.say;
```

//output "alert("something");"

Comment: Can you get someone to help with your English? And at the same time give more details? Right now, it's really unclear what you want to do. You *may* be talking about a "setter" function, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i think this is what you're looking for:

```
$.fn.extend({
    Ozellik: function(attr) {
        return this.attr(attr);
    }
});
```

Then:

```
<a id="mavi">link</a>

$('a').Ozellik('id')// > 'mavi'
```

You can apply this to plain JavaScript aswell:

```
Element.prototype.Ozellik = function(attr) {
    return this.getAttribute(attr);
};
```

Then:

```
<a id="mavi">link</a>

var _elem = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
_elem.Ozellik('id'); // > 'mavi'
```

Comment: sinan bey türkçe açıklasam ?

Comment: kısacası sondan eklenipte kullanılabilen bir method yazmak istiyorum

Comment: Benim ekledim gibi mi? Yoksa person() kapatigindan sonra eklemek mi istiyorsun?

Comment: var a = $("span");
alert(a.Ozellik("id"));

a bir obje bunun gibi bi function istiyorum adını dahi bulamadım hiç bir yerde

Comment: @UğurCanbulat Cozumu yeniledim, ama bu sadece jQuery elementlarile calisir

Comment: javascriptte durum nedir ? onda nasıl yapıcaz library oluşturmaya çalışıyorum aynı mantıkla C#tada aynı tip metod kullanmayı düşünüyorum adı ne bahsi geçen metodun ?
Daha doğrusu ne diye bulabilirim ?

Comment: @UğurCanbulat Degisik teknikleri var. Bu [kitap](http://bdcampbell.net/javascript/book/javascript_the_good_parts.pdf) sayfa 46'den ileri iyi orneklerile aciklaniyor. (pdf'in 62 uncu sayfa)